# Не находится класс Giant. NameError: name 'Giant' is not defined

Tags: python

```
class Race(Giant, Elf, Human):
    pass


class Human(Hero, Race):
    pass


class Giant(Hero, Race):
    pass

    
class Elf(Hero, Race):
    pass
```

Comment: Класс-родитель не может наследоваться от своих классов-потомков, это абсурд какой-то

Comment: Не надо `Race` от своих потомков наследовать, просто уберите их из аргументов класса.

Comment: Высоким слогом: граф наследования не должен содержать циклы.